# Elastic Search Kibana Tag Cloud

Tags: python, apache-spark, elasticsearch, spark-streaming, kibana

I have a streaming data from Spark Streaming that I have written into Elastic Search and am trying to visualize the data using Kibana .

My data has the following fields :

[image]

of all these fields , the ones containing '.keyword' as suffix were not created by me and I don't understand how they got mixed up with the string fields .

The problem is , when I try to create a tag cloud for the 'text' field , it does not even appear as one of the fields and only those string fields ending with '.keyword' are shown as valid options :

[image]

Why does this happen ? How do I create a tag cloud for the 'text' field alone ? I don't want the '.keyword' fields.

Could someone help me ?

Answer (score 2):

The `keyword` fields are your friend when it comes to doing exact searches and terms aggregations on them. And that's exactly what a tag cloud does, it's a `terms` aggregation, so `text.keyword` is the field you need to pick for that visualization.

The `text` field doesn't come up in the list because its content is analyzed (because it's of type `text`) and terms aggregations don't run on analyzed data.